# powershell match a string with parenthesis/brackets

Tags: powershell, match, brackets

I have the following small code:

```
foreach($u in $playbackDevices){
    if ($u -match $d.Name){
        $qualifiedPlaybackDeviceList.Add($d)
    }
}
```

The problem arises when:
$u="Digital Audio (HDMI)" and
$d.Name="Digital Audio (HDMI) (2- High Definition Audio Device)"

Obviously $u is contained in $d.Name, but due to the paranthesis in both string and pattern, they are not matched correctly. Some values of both variable contains both "()" and "[]".

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If `$u` is contained in `$d.Name` then `$d.Name` should be on the left-hand side of the comparison and if using the `-match` operator and considering `$u` could contain regex reserved characters, then you can use [`Regex.Escape` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape?view=net-7.0):

```bash
$u = 'Digital Audio (HDMI)'
$d = 'Digital Audio (HDMI) (2- High Definition Audio Device)'
$d -match $u                  # false
$d -match [regex]::Escape($u) # true
```

Alternatively, you can use the wildcard operator `-like`, but if `$u` could contain [wildcard characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-7.3#long-description), then it would also require escaping via [`WildcardPattern.Escape`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.wildcardpattern.escape?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0#system-management-automation-wildcardpattern-escape(system-string)), i.e.:

```bash
$u = 'Digital Audio [HDMI]'
$d = 'Digital Audio [HDMI] (2- High Definition Audio Device)'
$d -like "$u*"                                # false
$d -like "$([WildcardPattern]::Escape($u))*"  # true
```

Other option is [`string.Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=net-7.0) which would not require any kind of escaping as strings are matched literally, downside is this method is case-sensitive by default and in Windows PowerShell (5.1 and below) the only option would be `.ToLower()` or `.ToUpper()` both sides if we wanted case-insensitivity comparison:

```bash
$u = 'digital audio [HDMI]'
$d = 'Digital Audio [HDMI] (2- High Definition Audio Device)'
$d.Contains($u)                                       # false
$d.ToLowerInvariant().Contains($u.ToLowerInvariant()) # true
```

Or, if you're using a newer version of PowerShell (7+), we have the `StringComparison` overload:

```bash
$u = 'digital audio [HDMI]'
$d = 'Digital Audio [HDMI] (2- High Definition Audio Device)'
$d.Contains($u, [System.StringComparison]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) # true
```